# AngularJS 1.3 Routing not working; Controller never called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I can't for the life of me get AngularJS to work properly. I am not messing with templates or anything of that nature yet, I'm just trying to get the call to the controller to work correctly.

Here is a portion of my homepage.html

```
<div class="row" ng-app="eventsApp">
    <div class="column small-12 content">

        <p>Temporary Test.</p>
        <div ng-view></div>
        <ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-4 large-block-grid-5 shots">
            <li>
                <div class="thumb">
                    <a href="#Testing">
                        <div class="ctr-show s1">
                            <div class="show"><i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-lg"></i></div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="/img/screenshots/thumbs/g" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
...
```

Here is my app.js

```
'use strict';

var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', [
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
]);

alert("testing number 1");

eventsApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider.
when('/Testing', {
    templateUrl : 'Views/AngularViews/temp.html',
    controller : 'TestingController'
});
}]);
```

Later on in the app.js....

```
eventsApp.controller('TestingController', 
function($scope) {
    alert("testing number 2");

});
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing incorrectly? It just isn't working at all. The first alert pops up just fine, the second one never pops up, even after using the correct route.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must provide a template. Probly you are getting a error 404. Each template will be loaded inside the ng-view tag at the homepage, then the controller assigned to this route will run. And don't forget to call the route as myappurl/#/Testing

Comment: I'm getting nothing, no 404, nothing is happening at all. the URL changes, and that's it, the page doesn't change whatsoever. The alert doesn't run, I can force it to get a 404 if I put in just /Testing.  Can you explain that about the route?

Comment: there is no error on console?

Comment: @Brian single page route works with # between the site url and sub url, then you must use /#/Testing

Comment: The problem is that you are not providing any templateUrl

Comment: I added in a templateUrl after Fals comment, and nothing changed. I still have no errors. I'll update the code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code in coffeescript that works, I cannot spot any error in your implementation (and since there is no error on console...)

```
App.config [

  '$provide'
  '$routeProvider'

  ($provide, $routeProvider) ->

  $routeProvider
      .when('/testing', {
        templateUrl: 'test.hml'
        controller : 'TestingController'
      })
]

iDsign.App.controller('TestingController', ($scope)->

  alert('something')
)
```